# Change button "username" into text field once the operation is done iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

[image]

I'm working on profile user level, and I noticed in different apps the fact they can do what I'm going to explain below :

1. From profile page the new user tape on a button : username
2. they go to another page to choose a username
3. after that they go to choose password
4. once everything it's done they comeback to profile page

I want make the initial button username --> username textfield once the operation it's done

Thanks

Comment: hide the button by checking your conditions and make the text field visible.

Comment: Cannot understand your question clearly. Do you mean that you want to hide first button and show a textfield instead of it after login?

Comment: How can I hide the button by code swift ? @MukeshThawani

Comment: See my answer, it is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check conditions when a user has already entered his name then hide your button and when user has not entered username then hide text field. You can hide the button by using `button.hidden = true` and make it false if you want to show your button or a text field.

Comment: I have a question for you ! If the button2 is an other view controller and, and the button (the one who have to be hidden once the button 2 is tapped ) is in an other viewcontroller, Can I attribute the same UIviewcontroller to two view controller ? If yes I have this merssage error @MukeshThawani

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: You have to transfer the state of a button or whatever condition to that other view controller according to which you will display or hide the button in that view controller. Which you can do that using NSUserDefaults or if you are using segue then you can transfer through segue.

Comment: I'm little bit new on swift can you give some code to understand more how to do that ? thank u

Comment: NSUserdefaults is mainly used to transfer something inside your app, in your case you want to transfer particular condition. So transfer one variable which contains true or false and then read this on next view controller. Read about NSUserDefaults here http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/.

Comment: You can read about the error you were getting here is my answer on that http://stackoverflow.com/a/33077401/3637751

Comment: thank you ! but it will help if you show me a little bit of the code I have to implement

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding about my question above, I wanted to make the button1 disappear and let the textLabel take his place once the button is 2  is tapped

Comment: I added a picture of my problem above @MukeshThawani

Comment: instead of Hidden it will be delete!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090061/make-the-button1-disappear-and-let-the-textlabel-take-his-place-once-the-button

Comment: Sorry it's monday I was a little confused ! now is working :)